# Visual Studio REST Web Service - multiple WebInvoke

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I'm relatively new to creating web services; I have successfully created a web service using a test periodic table db table.
I have used multiple OperationContract to get the details:

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByName/{elementName}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByName(string elementName);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementBySymbol/{elementSymbol}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsBySymbol(string elementSymbol);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByAtomicNumber/{atomicNumber}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);
```

These all work fine. But I want to allow the user to use additional UriTemplates for the same call, for instance getting the details by number I want them to also be able to use

{webaddr}/GetElementByAtomicNumber(5)
   or
{webaddr}/GetElementByAtomicNumber?an=5

which can still use the same method to get the same result: 
ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);
If I use this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByAtomicNumber/{atomicNumber}")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByAtomicNumber({atomicNumber})")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementDetails?an={atomicNumber}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);
```

I get an error (duplicate invoke) and if I use this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByAtomicNumber{atomicNumber}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementByAtomicNumber({atomicNumber})")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetElementDetails?an={atomicNumber}")]
    ElementDetails getDetailsByAtomicNumber(string atomicNumber);
```

Then I also get an error: 
'PTRestService.IPeriodicTableRest' already defines a member called 'getDetailsByAtomicNumber'

So if I want to give the user some leeway like this do I need to create a unique implementation method for every call, even though it's doing the same thing?
Sorry if it seems naïve, it's because it is.
Thanks. 
Chris